# Domino Designer: Export a view to CSV File using formula language

Tags: lotus-notes, export-to-csv, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

In Domino Designer, I would like to export a view to CSV file, with the details as per below:

- Select all document
- In UTF-8
- Include Column Title

I tried to use formula language to at least export it to csv, and save it at the current user's desktop, but it seems like %UserProfile% is not working.

@Command([FileExport];"Comma Separated Value";"C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Desktop\temp.csv")

I have tried to change "%UserProfile%" with Public, and it works, but preferably I wish it could be done using current user profile.

My questions are:

1. Can I use formula language to code something like this?
2. Is there any lotusscript similar to my description as above (i.e The CSV file can be exported only by one click?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. No
2. Yes, see [example](http://www.falsepositives.com/index.php/2006/12/07/sntt-export-any-lotus-notes-view-to-csv-or-excel-automagically/) as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I don't 100% agree with 1. There is a "Workaround" that might not work in every windows version: In my Windows the environment variables can be found in the Registry in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment". If that is the case for you as well, you might use: `@RegQueryValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER"; "Volatile Environment"; "USERPROFILE")` to get UserProfile- value and put it in path like `@RegQueryValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER"; "Volatile Environment"; "USERPROFILE") + "Desktop\\temp.csv"`